# Different font size text on opposite ends of the same line

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

On react native, I am trying to get two different fonts on the same line. This part can be done relatively easy using nested `<Text>`.

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>
  twelve<Text style={{fontSize: 14}}>fourteen</Text>
<Text>
```

Now I wish to get the two texts on opposite ends of the screen (horizontally). The desired effect is as seen below, where the two 'hi's are on opposite ends of the screen width.

[image]

Is this achievable in react native? If possible I would like to avoid using manual padding adjustments.

**Edit:** We have to achieve two things at the same time here, 1) on the same line and 2) opposite ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by flexDirection and JustifyContent.

```
<View style={{
                    margin: 20,
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    alignItems: 'baseline',
                }}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 22, lineHeight: 22}}>
                        Hi
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 25, lineHeight: 25}}>
                        Hi
                    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Since you probably want the text to be on the same line, try adding `alignItems: 'flex-end'`to the parent `<View>`

Comment: I have tried this, along with adding `alignItems: 'flex-end'` but they do not seem to be on the same line (while they are on the same line using the nested text method, they cant be on opposite ends). Do appreciate your attempt!

Comment: @MayankJain Sorry, your answer does not make the text rest on the same line, even with the addition of `alignItems: 'flex-end'`. Please try it, look closely you will notice they are off.

Comment: @iWillGetBetter try with lineHeight and alignItems: 'baseline'

Comment: @MayankJain can you edit your answer to include alignItems: 'baseline', will accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<Text 
  style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>Hi 
    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 30 }}>Hi
    </Text>
</Text>
```